# Should I redirect the directory listing page of a parallel secondary directory to the primary directory?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, redirects, directory-listing

I have a website where I have a few sub-directories to list services. So it goes like this.

- `example.com/services/website-development.html`
- `example.com/services/web-development/e-commerce.html`
- `example.com/services/web-development/wordpress.html`

I used `web-development` because I couldn't use a directory with the name `website-development` as `example.com/services/website-development.html` is a page.

Now the problem is that Google is has crawled the directory listing page at `example.com/services/web-development`.   It is trying to index the page and I'm getting mobile usability errors in Search Console:

> Text too small to read, Clickable elements too close together, Viewport not set

There is no `index.html` in that directory.

Is redirecting that URL to the `website-development.html` URL the best way to deal with the situation?

Answer (score 1):

If there is not site at example.com/services/web-development, you can use a redirect to push anything that accesses that URL to the correct place, maybe also use a sitemap.xml to define what Google indexes.

Using htaccess in your root level of your web server, how you redirect one page to another is:

```
RewriteRule ^url-string-to-redirect$ http://www.yourdomain.com/your-new-url-string [R=301,L]
```

Or

```
Redirect 301 /path/to-old-url    http://www.cyourdomain.com/path/to-new-url
```

To redirect the contents of a whole directory to another use the below:

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /anotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

To redirect the contents of a whole directory to the webserving root:

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

To redirect the contents of a subdirectory to another domain but in the same subdirectory

```
Redirect 301 /subdirectory http://www.anotherdomain.com/subdirectory
```

Make sure that the opening of the .htaccess file contains the 2 lines of code below which enables the Apache module to rewrite the URLS, then place your redirections below them

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Thanks @LinuxSurfaceNut, there is nothing at example.com/services/web-development. I'm just using it as a directory so that I could include more "web development" services inside. So example.com/services/web-development/wordpress.html

Comment: I think if I redirect example.com/services/web-development/ to another page, all pages in that directory will also be re-directed